# How to play video on image target vuforia and unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I want to autoplay video on image target.

I am working with vuforia and unity..

P.S. I tried to do this with vuforia video playback but its not working

Comment: Whats the problem? Please take a screen shot in runtime. Especially show video playback prefab. Common probles are video codec or video doesn't place in correct folder. (StreamingAssets.)(Look at [this](https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/unity-3-extension-technical-discussion/videoplayback-video-stored-outside-streaming-assets).)

Answer (score 1):

You have to configure it inside `DefaultTrackableEventHandler` class.
Take a video player variable inside the above mentioned class.

```
public VideoPlayer vidPlay;
```

Now inside `OnTrackableStateChanged` configure it like this:

```
vidPlay = mTrackableBehaviour.GetComponentInChildren<VideoPlayer>();
//This will get current component video
```

Now `Play` or `Pause` your video according to your need. An snippet would be like this:

```
if (newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.DETECTED ||
     newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.TRACKED ||
     newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.EXTENDED_TRACKED)
 {
     vidPlay.Play();
     OnTrackingFound();
 }
 else
 {
     vidPlay.Pause();
     OnTrackingLost();
 }
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a Unity thing, after you apply the video to the object in your scene, you will then need to create a script attached to the object that plays the video:

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MovieTexture.Play.html
http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-MovieTexture.html

Answer (score 0):

Create a plane inside image target and add VideoPlayer on top of Plane. 
Select VideoPlayer. Go to Render mode, select Material Override. In Renderer drag and drop plane.

[image]